# Can we create a train_test_split from 1-D Tensors?

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, train-test-split

I am trying to create a train test split from my X and y data which are tensors returned from tf.range() function. But it shows me that only slices, integers, ellipses, scalar are valid values. That's what basically I want to do with my **Keras** model:

```
# Let's see if our model can be used for a regression problem...
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Create some regression data
X_regression = tf.range(0, 1000, 5)
y_regression = tf.range(100, 1100, 5) # y = X + 100

# Split our regression data into training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_reg_train, X_reg_test, y_reg_train, y_reg_test = train_test_split(X_regression, y_regression, test_size = 0.25)
```

I tried to create the split but it is throwing me following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-24-eec7af599ec5> in <module>
      8 # Split our regression data into training and test sets
      9 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
---> 10 X_reg_train, X_reg_test, y_reg_train, y_reg_test = train_test_split(X_regression, y_regression, test_size = 0.25)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in _check_index(idx)
    905     # TODO(slebedev): IndexError seems more appropriate here, but it
    906     # will break `_slice_helper` contract.
--> 907     raise TypeError(_SLICE_TYPE_ERROR + ", got {!r}".format(idx))
    908 
    909 

TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got array([ 86,  50,  57, 156,  44,   1, 147, 163,  77,  15,  96,  23, 194,
        91,  36,  80,  40, 174, 101,  30, 153, 159, 100, 185, 164,  56,
        55, 172,  37,  34,  84, 120, 179,  64, 143,  16,  49,  20, 137,
         9,  65,   3, 123,  27,   4, 122, 152,  78,  69,  18,  97,  32,
       171, 184,  48, 133, 118,  79,  62, 129,  54,  83, 186, 180, 111,
       182,  88,  33, 106, 170, 169,  13,   2, 126,  14, 187, 105,  85,
        74, 139, 168, 175, 173, 103,   5, 119,  29,  81,  76,  41, 165,
        12, 158,  82, 104, 145,  70,  99, 138, 146, 178,  68,  38, 140,
       160, 117, 155, 148, 142,  92,  11,  22, 124, 162,  87,  28, 127,
        53,  47,  52, 176,  45,  72,  21, 150, 181, 136,  26,  17, 130,
       196, 132, 149, 183,  39,  59, 128, 121, 188,   6, 157,  51,   8,
       167, 113, 112,  75,  73,  24,  31])
```

Comment: use python's `range` built-in function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `range` function and `tf.convert_to_tensor`.

```
# Let's see if our model can be used for a regression problem...
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Create some regression data
import tensorflow as tf
X_regression = range(0, 1000, 5)
y_regression = range(100, 1100, 5) # y = X + 100

# Split our regression data into training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_reg_train, X_reg_test, y_reg_train, y_reg_test = train_test_split(X_regression, y_regression, test_size = 0.25)
X_reg_train, X_reg_test, y_reg_train, y_reg_test = 
tf.convert_to_tensor(X_reg_train), tf.convert_to_tensor(X_reg_test), 
tf.convert_to_tensor(y_reg_train), tf.convert_to_tensor(y_reg_test)
```